# Move Welcome Greet Message to header panel

Tags: magento2, theme, jquery, porto-theme

I am using smarthwave porto theme, in which I need to move the Default Welcome Message from Nav Menu (shown in screenshot 1) to main header panel (which is in blue color at top)(shown in screenshot 2) in **MOBILE VIEW** only.

[image]

And I want to move it to here,

[image]

Thank you in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by customization.
In the themes header.php, I have added the custom div for appending.
For example, I am using smartwave porto theme, so I have added in the following path

> app\design\frontend\Companyname\Themename\Smartwave_Porto\templates\html\header.php

and added the following code

```
<div class="custom-wrapper"></div>
```

After doing that, I have made customization in theme's js.
Code goes like this

```
require([
      'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        $(window).on('resize', function(){
            var win = $(this); //this = window
            var isLoggedIn = $('.authorization-link > a').attr('href').indexOf('/login')<0;
            if (win.innerWidth() < 991) {
                if(isLoggedIn){
                    $(".header.panel .greet .logged-in").appendTo(".custom-wrapper");
                }else{
                    $(".header.panel .greet .not-logged-in").appendTo(".custom-wrapper");
                }
            }else{
                if(isLoggedIn){
                    $("#html-body > div.page-wrapper > header > nav > div > div > div > div > div.header-right > div.custom-wrapper").appendTo("#html-body > div.page-wrapper > header > nav > div > div > div > div > div.header-right > div.panel.header.show-icon-tablet > ul > li.greet.welcome");
                }else{
                    $("#html-body > div.page-wrapper > header > nav > div > div > div > div > div.header-right > div.custom-wrapper").appendTo("#html-body > div.page-wrapper > header > nav > div > div > div > div > div.header-right > div.panel.header.show-icon-tablet > ul > li.greet.welcome");
                }
            } 
            if(win.innerWidth() >= 991) {
                if(isLoggedIn){
                    $("#html-body > div.page-wrapper > header > nav > div > div > div > div > div.custom-wrapper").appendTo("#html-body div.page-wrapper header div.main-panel-top div div div div.header-right div ul li.greet.welcome");
                }else{
                    $("#html-body > div.page-wrapper > header > nav > div > div > div > div > div.custom-wrapper").appendTo("#html-body div.page-wrapper header div.main-panel-top div div div div.header-right div ul li.greet.welcome");
                }
            }else{
                if(isLoggedIn){
                    $("#html-body > div.page-wrapper > header > nav > div > div > div > div > div.header-right > div > ul > li.greet.welcome > div").insertBefore(".main-panel-inner .header-right .header.panel");
                }else{
                    $("#html-body > div.page-wrapper > header > nav > div > div > div > div > div.header-right > div > ul > li.greet.welcome > div").insertBefore(".main-panel-inner .header-right .header.panel");
                }
            }
        });
        $(window).resize();
    });
```